# Change dialog settings on a webbrowser's savedialog

Tags: c#, .net, dialog, save

I am working with a webbrowser. When I call the ShowSaveAsDialog, I want to be able to choose a default filename and a default extension type for it. How can I do this? I do not see any way of modifying the dialog box that pops up there.

If I cannot do that, how can I save the contents of my webbrowser to a file of my choice (htm/html file for example)?

Comment: Are you just asking how to change the save filter?

saveFileDialog1.Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif"

There's also a .DefaultExt and .DefaultFileName property as well.

Comment: No, the webbrowser has a ShowSaveAsDialog method with it's own dialog. If I don't use that, I was asking how I could save the HTML to a file using a normal dialog (as you just mentioned).